# Is it possible to maintain a global (across all apps) migration history with South?

Tags: python, django, django-south

I've run into a similar problem to [What migration order does South follow across different apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474745/what-migration-order-does-south-follow-across-different-apps), where migrations from different apps (say app_a and app_b) have to be interleaved in order to work, but South runs all migrations from app_a first, and then all migrations from app_b, by default.

I know there's a way to [manually specify dependencies to make it work](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependencies.html), but this seems unnecessary since the global order of how migrations were run could be recorded by South, so it could interleave them according to how they were actually interleaved in the past.

So, is there a good way to have South remember your global migration history and setup the dependencies automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is needed: recording the order in which migrations are run would introduce more dependencies than needed (as most migrations of apps can - and should - be run independently of other apps). You simply need to specify the dependencies yourself as you know which ones need to come before others.

Also, the order in which migrations run doesn't really "exist": there are simply multiple databases (local, development, production) and a set of apps that each have some migrations. These migrations simply need to run and you'll want the least number of dependencies as possible. Specifying one particular order in which all migrations need to run is a needless limitation.

If another developer decides to migrate the apps in a different order then that should be possible. The only limitation should be the hard dependencies that you have specified with [depends_on](http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/Dependencies).

It may be more manual labor now but if your apps are not too intertwined then you should not have too many dependencies between apps. If you do then you may need to consider merging those apps as they are more related than you thought?

Comment: I up-voted your answer, but I don't feel right (semantically) marking it as the 'accepted answer' because it doesn't directly answer the question.